# Highlight minimum and maximum points in faceted ggplot2 graph in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

I am using the built-in `economics` (from the `ggplot2` package) dataset in R, and have plotted a time-series for each variable in the same graph using the following code :

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

me <- melt(economics, id = c("date"))
ggplot(data = me) + 
     geom_line(aes(x = date, y = value)) +
     facet_wrap(~variable, ncol = 1, scales = 'free_y')
```

Now, I further want to refine my graph, For each series, I want to display a red point for the smallest and the largest value.
So I thought if I could find the co-ordinates of the min and max of each time-series, I could find a way to plot a red dot at beginning and ending of each time series. For this I used the following code :

```
which(pce == min(economics$pce), arr.ind = TRUE) 
which(pca == max(pca), arr.ind = TRUE)
```

This doesnt really lead me anywhere. 
Thank you:)

Comment: Probably not why your code isn't working, but you can use `which.max` and `which.min` to get the index of the max and min values.

Comment: Also, in your min code, it should probably be `economics$pce == min(economics$pce)`. That might be it.

Comment: @Molx I am trying to find the minimum and maximum value for each variable, and produce it on the graph. So once I know the minimum of a variable (y-axis), how can i find the value of date for the minimum (x-axis)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Method 1: Using Joins

*This can be nice when you want to save the filtered subsets*

---

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

me <- melt(economics, id=c("date"))

me %>%
  group_by(variable) %>%
  summarise(min = min(value),
            max = max(value)) -> me.2

left_join(me, me.2) %>%
  mutate(color = value == min | value == max) %>%
  filter(color == TRUE) -> me.3

ggplot(data=me, aes(x = date, y = value)) + 
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(data=me.3, aes(x = date, y = value), color = "red") +
  facet_wrap(~variable, ncol=1, scales='free_y')
```

### Method 2: Simplified without Joins

*Thanks @Gregor*

```
me.2 <- me %>%
  group_by(variable) %>%
  mutate(color = (min(value) == value | max(value) == value))

ggplot(data=me.2, aes(x = date, y = value)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(aes(color = color)) +
  facet_wrap(~variable, ncol=1, scales="free_y") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(NA, "red"))
```

[image: Plot]

Comment: Some simplification: `me <- group_by(me, variable) %>% mutate(color = (min(value) == value | max(value) == value))` No need for joining.

Comment: Then for the plot, you don't need to give it extra data, just set the color for points you don't like to `NA`, like this: `geom_point(aes(color = color)) + scale_color_manual(values = c(NA, "red"))`

Comment: @Jason I was thinking more in terms or transform, summarise and subset. Could you please help me with that.